# Angular5:- Can't bind to 'showNavigationArrows' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-carousel'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap 1.x.x with Angular5, bootstrap4 and I need to cusomize the NavigationArrows based on dynamic data but i am getting while accessing it from HTML

App.module.ts

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
imports[NgbModule.forRoot()]
```

In app/accounts
accounts.module.ts

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    imports[NgbModule.] // tried with NgbModule.forRoot().
```

HTML

```
<ngb-carousel   #ngbCarouselid="ngbCarousel" [showNavigationArrows]="false"  [interval]="false" [wrap]="false" *ngIf="numReceipts() > 0" class="center-block no-indicators image-view">
</ngb-carousel>
```

`[interval], [wrap]` works fine but `[showNavigationArrows]` is giving me below error

```
Can't bind to 'showNavigationArrows' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-carousel'.
1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'showNavigationArrows' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div class="imgCarousel">

      <ngb-carousel   #ngbCarouselid="ngbCarousel" [ERROR ->][showNavigationArrows]="false"  [interval]="false" [wrap]="false" *ngIf="numReceipts() > 0" class="ce"): ng:///AccountsModule/ReceiptPreviewComponent.html@28:51
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'showNavigationArrows' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-carousel'.
1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'showNavigationArrows' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div class="imgCarousel">
```

Comment: It was added in version 2.2 https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api

Answer (score 3):

You need to add to the app.module.ts file:

```
 import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

and after imports:[], add

```
 schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
```

hope this helped you :)